# Making internal website available publicly (Win 2008 Server)

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, firebox

I have an IIS 7 web site that is running on a Windows 2008 Server (64-bit) VMWare on a Windows 2008 Server (64-bit) Host on my local network. My router is a Firebox XEdge and it has port 80 directed to the IP of the server on VMWare.

I can reach the web site from inside the network, but I cannot reach the site from outside the network. I have other web sites that are working through the Firebox, and I am confident that it is configured correctly.

I suspect that Windows 2008 server is blocking routed or public addresses, but I have shut down the firewall on the Server that is running on VMWare and the AVG Anti-virus to no avail.

How can I make my site available publicly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you've configured your firebox correctly? I suspect that you haven't created the correct policy.

What you want is a policy for port 80 allowing from **Any-External** to **static nat** (outside IP -> internal ip).

Comment: We have other web servers that are working through the same firebox with identical configurations only different external and internal IP addresses. The only web servers that gives me headaches are the ones running Windows Server 2008.

Comment: I have found the problem. There was an "out of service" router using the outside IP address.

Comment: Nice. I'm glad you figured it out.